ld statically linking my program despite -dynamic-linker option
I am following a tutorial on assembly programming. I did exactly the same as the author, but when I link the hello64.o with ld, my file size is 8kb, not 1kb like in the tutorial.
I checked the elf file with the file command and it says it is statically linked, which I'm guessing is why it is bigger.
I tried linking using -I and -dynamic-linker, but they still end up statically linked.
global _start

SYS_WRITE       equ 1
SYS_EXIT        equ 60
STDOUT          equ 1

SECTION .data
hello           db      "Hello World!", 10
hello_len       equ     $-hello

SECTION .text

_start:
        mov             rax, SYS_WRITE
        mov             rdi, STDOUT
        mov             rsi, hello
        mov             rdx, hello_len
        syscall
        push            rax

        mov             rax, SYS_EXIT
        pop             rdi
        sub             rdi, hello_len
        syscall

this is the asm file I used to create the object file, hello64.o. Besides the comments being removed, it is identical to the one in the tutorial.
$ ld -o hello64 hello64.o
$ file hello64
hello64: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
$ ld -o hello64_2 hello64.o -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 
$ file hello64_2
hello64_2: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
$ wc -c hello64_2
8976 hello64_2

As you can see both are statically linked
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you for your time.

You did not use any libraries, so there is no extra code included. You could make a PIE if you insist on some use of the dynamic linker. If you want smaller size put your string into the .text section.

@Jester Thank you! But why was it so much smaller for the author of the tutorial without doing anything?

The default linker script didn't use to align sections to pages, so there used to be an executable mapping of the .data initializers, etc.  (Which is bad for security with ROP attacks and Spectre).  Minimal executable size now 10x larger after linking than 2 years ago, for tiny programs?

that really cleared things up, thank you!
